# Is reseeding OpenSSL CSPRNG necessary if using RAND_bytes?

Tags: openssl, c++, random

I read that cryprographic secure PRNG (CSPRNG) need a random seed to provide random output. Looking at OpenSSL that seems to be archived by `RAND_poll()` and random data is fetched with `RAND_bytes(buf, length)`.

But I'm quite not sure if I get everything right that is stated in the [documentation here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers). I know that `RAND_bytes` will call `RAND_poll()` itself if it was not called before at least once.

I also read (somewhere else) that a seed should not be reused for a CSPRNG. Now my question is: Does `RAND_bytes` reuse any seed? Do I have to manually reseed OpenSSL for distinct `RAND_bytes` calls by using `RAND_bytes(buf, length)` again and again if i do not want reuse the seed?

Or does `RAND_bytes` manage this by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does `RAND_bytes` reuse any seed?

Kindof.
Re-using a seed is bad, because it will give you the exact same random numbers again. OpenSSL doesn't do this. However, you're allowed to use the one seed obtained by the first `RAND_poll` as long as you want (which is not advisable) as the PRNG will generate a steady stream of (unpredictable) bytes based on this one seed and you will just be served "later" parts in the stream if you don't reseed.

You should re-seed the PRNG as often as possible if you have entropy rich data, but it will also work (quite securely) if you don't do this.

**Final answer: `RAND_bytes` (kindof) manages this itself.**